# Constructing a random string

Tags: python

How to construct a string to have more than 5 characters and maximum of 15 characters using random function in python

```
    import string

    letters = list(string.lowercase)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After the import and assignment you already have, assuming you want all possible lengths with the same probability:

```
import random

length = random.randrange(5, 16)

randstr = ''.join(random.choice(letters) for _ in range(length))
```

Comment: @Hulk, as the docs at http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.randrange say, randrange was new in version 1.5.2.  No idea why you think you can't use it 8 versions later than than time?!