# Random combination of letters?

Tags: python, random

Using Python, how can I get a randomized combination of letters?

I want to do something like this:

```
def ranStr():
    # some code
    return random_string
```

So, if I call `ranStr()`, I want to get out things like (random combination of random length of letters):

```
'aAFGresdFTg'
'EFRwdfWe'
'rgAijD'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: And more likely your question won't be closed if you follow what Martijn just wrote to you :)

Comment: It is now closed, but a [edit] of your post could save it still; make it a real question and you can ask for a reopen.

Comment: I think if you just copy some of the questions from here that would work.

Comment: duplicate question:  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539945/constructing-a-random-string

Answer (score 2):

This is one way of doing it.

```
import random
def generate_key():
    STR_KEY_GEN = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    return ''.join(random.choice(STR_KEY_GEN) for _ in xrange(70))
```

OR

```
import random, string
def generate_key():
    return ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for _ in xrange(70))
```

Based on the suggestions.

Comment: Better: STR_KEY_GEN = string.letters

Comment: You don't need to type out the whole alphabet by the way. Have a look into the [`string` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.ascii_letters)

Comment: `random.choice(string.letters)` gets a random letter, just keep doing it for a `randint` amount of times to get a random string.